# Renaming files with Flutter in newer Android API versions (Android version >11)

Tags: flutter, dart, filesystems

In my app, I have a need to perform some file system operations. One of them is renaming a file to a certain name generated by the app.

I am using the following code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

final String videoPath; 


Future requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
  print("Requesting permission: $permission");
  PermissionStatus status = await permission.status;
  print("Permission status: $status");

  if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    print("Permission is permanently denied");
  } else if (status.isDenied) {
    print("Permission is denied");
    status = await permission.request();
    print("Permission status on requesting again: $status");
  } else {
    print("Permission is not permanently denied");
    status = await permission.request();
  }
}

Future<File> changeFileNameOnly(File file, String newFileName) async {
  await requestPermission(Permission.photos);
  await requestPermission(Permission.videos);
  var path = file.path;
  var lastSeparator = path.lastIndexOf(Platform.pathSeparator);
  var newPath = path.substring(0, lastSeparator + 1) + newFileName;
  return file.rename(newPath);
}

await requestPermission(Permission.photos);
await requestPermission(Permission.videos);
File f = await changeFileNameOnly(File(widget.videoPath), _filenameController.text);
print("Done")
```

The output:

```
I/flutter ( 7884): In changeFileNameOnly...
I/flutter ( 7884): Requesting permission: Permission.photos
I/flutter ( 7884): Permission status: PermissionStatus.granted
I/flutter ( 7884): Permission is not permanently denied
I/flutter ( 7884): Requesting permission: Permission.videos
I/flutter ( 7884): Permission status: PermissionStatus.granted
I/flutter ( 7884): Permission is not permanently denied
E/flutter ( 7884): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathAccessException: Cannot rename file to '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/a.mp4', path = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20230309_181203.mp4' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
E/flutter ( 7884): #0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:55:9)
E/flutter ( 7884): #1      _File.rename.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:335:7)
E/flutter ( 7884): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7884): #2      _FullScreenVideoViewState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
video_view.dart:308
E/flutter ( 7884): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7884):
```

My AndroidManifest.xml has the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

My development phone is a Samsung Galaxy 23 Ultra runnig Android 13.

What is the proper way to rename files in newer API levels? Is there something in the way I do it? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question myself. The issue was wrong permission. Android 11 has apparently introduced something called Scoped Storage to limit file system access. I was requesting Audio and Video permission, but the permission I needed was "android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

So solution:
Add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And in my request, I need to add the line:

```
await requestPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage);
```

On doing this, at this line, System pops up the Setting which allows me to grant Storage access to my app. After that, renaming was done successfully.

Read [more.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)